# Invalid Ref Cursor with GWT on Tomcat

Tags: oracle, tomcat, gwt, jdbc

This is my first question in Stack Overflow!

I have a GWT application with an Oracle DB end. This application being developed in Eclipse and it runs fine with Google App Engine, however, when I deploy the application on Tomcat 7 then I get the following exception:

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    **java.sql.SQLException: Ref cursor is invalid**
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getCursorValue(OracleStatement.java)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.getCursor(OracleCallableStatement.java)
    at com.swisscom.tcr.tif.fdt.server.GreetingServiceImpl.getEnvCredentials(GreetingServiceImpl.java:6227)
    at com.swisscom.tcr.tif.fdt.server.GreetingServiceImpl.getOracleConnection_withGlobalSchemaTable(GreetingServiceImpl.java:4967)
    at com.swisscom.tcr.tif.fdt.server.GreetingServiceImpl.get_value(GreetingServiceImpl.java:962)
```

Just to clarify, the stored procs that are returning the Ref Cursors are working fine, so my guess is that this is a JDBC library clash.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure, the `CURSOR` you return is really valid one? You might  have attempted to fetch from a `REFCURSOR` which was not `OPEN`ed at all.. May be use can have some variables to indicate the success of `OPEN` cursor in proc and `FETCH` it in `JDBC` only when the indicator is `SUCCESS`.

Comment: @OracleUser: Thanks for taking thetime to answer. I did create a small application which execute 2 of the stored procs and it works. Also, as I mentioned above, my applications works fine if I run it on development environment i.e. in Eclipse.